# Rewriting the whole String Class methods

Tags: java, compareto

My professor have given me a challenging homework, where the idea is to rewrite all the methods in the String classes without using **String, StringBuilder, and Wrapper classes.** This is for Intro to Java class. I already have some methods done but having a hard time with some other ones. This is for the main class only with no creation of any string inside.

What I have: a **"data"** as a char[] data for my "MyOwnString" object.

CompareTo method:

```
public int compareTo(MyOwnString rhs){
    if (this.data == rhs.data){
        return 0;
    } else if (this.data > rhs.data){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

This one shows an error. My guess is that the rhs needs to be declare before being able to compare to any string being assigned to a MyOwnString object. 
Since there is a compareTo method and a compareToIgnoreCase, then I would have to add a line to ignore the comparsion?

---

**Update:**

This is the code I went with for the compareTo method by creating own method using length of the array.

```
public int compareTo(MyOwnString cts){
    int word1 = data.length;
    int word2 = cts.length();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<word1; i++){
        for (int j=0;j<word2; j++){
            if(word1 == word2){
                result = 0;
            }
            else if (word1 > word2){
                result = 1;
            }
            else {
                result = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```

Comment: I like that you have broken your homework in 3-4 stackoverflow questions...why don't you try writing those methods yourself? It is very easy for me to give you the full answer and get a reputation bump in a sec but I will resist :O)

Comment: I have tried to do them on my own. It is just I dont have enough experience and knowledge to be able to do it on my own that easily. Then you should certainly give this rookie the perfect Christmas gift this upcoming year. ;D

Comment: I know how it feels. Persevere and you will succeed. The reward of programming comes when you actually do it yourself and then do it better the next time - we are here to help but you have to say I have done this and I have done that  :)

Comment: Any updates/problems on String class replication? If you have something we could help you finalize it :)

Comment: @MichailMichailidis I was able to figure out the compareTo method by using the length. Now the trouble I am getting is how to get the change the array to lowercase to do the CompareToIgnoreCase method. I know I would have to use the same code I used for the compareTo. My guess is to put a method for putting the two object in lowercase in the beginning before doing the length.

Comment: Alright as I said in my updated answer below - don't just write code. Compile it. Up there you are using two loops that they are not needed (you are not doing comparison of one character with all the others). You have to compare only pairs. Also you are not even using i's and j's in your loop(s) and the result information that you are keeping is erased all the time so it doesn't make sense. Check my answer and if it is what you were looking for please accept it :)

Comment: your compareTo is totally wrong and very inefficient ! You compare word1*word2 times the three cases that don't change about the lengths word1 and word2 (you are not scanning the char pairs) .. In other words if you put a word which is shorter than the one that you are comparingTo but is alphanumerically before it - it will not work. The same if they have same lengths but are not equal! Please update your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to use String.compareTo()
and since java doesn't support > for your custom objects or char[] for that matter (e.g doesn't support operator overloading) you have to do it programmatically.

In other words you have the two char arrays and you have to loop through all the characters.  You compare the first two characters from each of the char arrays (there you can use > or <) if they are == you compare the second two characters and so on.. till you find two characters that break the tie - you can then break your for loop and return the result as -1, 1. If they are tied on every character you return 0.

If you want to implement equals you could just call compareTo and optimize it a bit by checking the lengths of the strings. If they are different then of course the strings are not equal

---

**Update:** I am not sure if you ran your code above - try to compile your code and run it before you move forward. I believe it won't even compile.
Here is, I believe, a correct unchecked version. I could have mixed the -1 and 1s as always..

```
public int compareTo(MyOwnString cts){
    int word1Length = ((MyOwnString)this).data.length;
    int word2Length = cts.data.length;
    for (int i=0; i < Math.min(word1Length,word2Length); i++){
        if(this.data[i] == cts.data[i]){
            continue;
        }
        else if (this.data[i] > cts.cts[i]){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.data[i] < cts.cts[i]) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    if (word1Length == word2Length){
        return 0;
    }
    else if(word1Length < word2Length){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

public boolean equals(MyOwnString cts){
    int word1Length = ((MyOwnString)this).data.length;
    int word2Length = cts.data.length;
    if (word1Length != word2Length){
        return false;
    }
    else { // if they are equal
        int comparison = this.compareTo(cts);
        if (comparison==0){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From what I am reading is that I would have to define this.data to a tempData, and the data to this.data, so that it would give me two arrays. Then I would use == and != to compare the two string? That is my guess.

Comment: No. Just do a for loop and advance each of the arrays to the ith position. Then hold those two characters in your for loop and compare them the way I describe above. If that is not enough or you don't understand exactly what I mean, I suggest going back to study and write some more code before trying the assignment ;)

Comment: Oh okay. I am understanding is that I would have to loop both arrays. Then create a for loop after that to compare them the way you describe above. 
I would love to learn more about Java. Can you give me more time without being rushed. xD

Comment: You only need a single loop for everything. If you want to learn fast and good Java from the basics to the most complex things you will ever need start watching some youtube video series like:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TBWX97e1E9g&list=PLE7E8B7F4856C9B19. Internet is making things way faster than when I was learning to code by reading ebooks. I guess I was still lucky because I had internet compared to 20 years ago :P. Always remember that you have to learn how to code and not specific language and get your hands DIRTY with coding!!

Comment: I just ran your first code and it encounter an error because the word1[i] and word2[i] wasnt declared the code, so the program doesnt know where word1[i] and word2[i] comes from. 
Your second code does work and it was what I was wondering because it converted my string to automatically lowercase. It is what Eclipse said about your first code. 
When using my code with addition with your second code for equals, it works perfectly.
Thanks for your help! :D

Comment: I fixed it - I had to use your variables with .data because this is your char[] array. Your compareTo is just comparing the i's and j's of the loop not the char[] array pairs so it should not work at all..

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `char[]` objects with the `>` operator, since it's not defined on them. You'll have to iterate over the `char[]` arrays and compare the characters yourself.

BTW, it's very easy to cheat in this assignment, since the code of the String class is available online.

Comment: As if the professor doesn't know the how compareTo is implemented in String class already :P

Comment: @Eran oh i see. The reason I did that was because the task was to return an int if the left object is greater than the right object of 1, and the opposite a -1. Thats why I add a > to the loop

Comment: @user4146749 Well, you can't use > on arrays, and currently I see no loop.

Comment: @MichailMichailidis well, i dont know. I am sure the professor knows what he is doing. Why else he is giving a challenging homework without using any shortcut. It is the same thing as if a 5x5x5 Rubik cube for a homework assignment. LOL

Comment: @Eran when you say iterate over the char[] array, you mean to say to list it out and compare it letter by letter?

Comment: @user4146749 Rubik is way more complicated than a for loop around two char arrays ;). I mean looping over it using for loop and go to the specific index positions and check the two characters. That should be easy from now on ;) - Oops I thought you were referring to me - nevermind ;)

Comment: @Eran what do you mean the code of the String class You mean the Java API website?

Comment: That is what he meant. But the code is not easy to understand let alone to copy paste it. Have a read though and see how things actually work internally http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/String.java.html